# Dismiss a view with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am popping the couponDetailsView with bounce animation. But i want to dismiss the view from left to right animation. How can i do this? Below is my source code. Any kind of help would be really helpful.

```
#pragma mark Bounce Animation


-(void) openContentDetailsView
{

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.couponDetailsView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:
     ^(void){
         self.couponDetailsView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,1.1f, 1.1f);
         self.couponDetailsView.alpha = 0.5;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self bounceOutAnimationStoped];
                     }];

}


- (void)bounceOutAnimationStoped
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:
     ^(void){
         self.couponDetailsView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,0.9, 0.9);
         self.couponDetailsView.alpha = 0.8;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self bounceInAnimationStoped];
                     }];
}
- (void)bounceInAnimationStoped
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:
     ^(void){
         self.couponDetailsView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,1, 1);
         self.couponDetailsView.alpha = 1.0;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self animationStoped];
                     }];
}
- (void)animationStoped
{


}
- (IBAction)contentDetailsCloseButtonAction:(id)sender {

    self.couponDetailsView.alpha = 0;
    self.couponDetailsView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,0.6, 0.6);

}
```

Comment: Instead of using a transform, simple change the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                  delay:0.0f
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
             animations:^{
                 [testView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [testView removeFromSuperview]; 
}];
```